# AccessibilityNodeInfo Incompatible Types

Tags: android

I have this code here below and I keep getting incompatible types, could someone explain to me how to fix this? Required is AccessibilityNodeInfo, but it finds charSequence.

```
 public static String getAppType(AccessibilityNodeInfo source)
{
    if (source == null) {
        return "";
    }

    source = source.getPackageName();  <<~~~~ This line is the problem

    if (source == null) {
        return "";
    }
    return source.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`source` is already defined as the type `AccessibilityNodeInfo`, it cannot be reassigned as a String. You need to create a new local variable,

```
public static String getAppType(AccessibilityNodeInfo source)
{
    if (source == null) {
        return "";
    }

    String pkg = source.getPackageName().toString();

    if (pkg == null) {
        return "";
    }
    return pkg;
}
```

Comment: This comes back as Required String, found Charsequence.

Comment: Updated the code to convert from CharSequence to String